# Having some issues with a R bar graph

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

I'm new to R and am very confused.
I'm trying to graph some data I have collected about Barbie's college majors, but the x axis labelling is bleeding onto the graph and getting cut off on the left side, any tips? Any other recommendations welcome.

[image: picture of the graph]

code:

```r
b <-  ggplot(total_barbies_per_major, aes(x = reorder(majors, -sum), y = sum)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "deeppink") +
    labs(title = "Barbie's Most Used Majors", x = "Majors", y = "Total Barbie Dolls") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)))
  print(b)
```

I tried adjusting the angle of the x axis but it made everything worse.

Comment: Welcome to SK, kate hudson! Questions on SO (and especially the [tag:r] tag) do much better when the are fully reproducible and self-contained, which means at least two components: minimum code to reproduce (which you have) and sample data are key. Please [edit] your question, then paste the output from `dput(total_barbies_per_major)` into a [code block] so that we can work with your data. Some good refs for "reproducibility": https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to what @r2evans said, even if you do manage to correctly align your axis text: 1) the density of text will make the plot difficult to interpret; 2) the length of the axis labels means your bar graph size gets compromised. I think a better way to approach this issue is to recategorise your values e.g. the science stuff becomes "STEM", law enforcement becomes "First Responder" etc. Or if your data allow, split the data further into smaller groupings. If you do split them, you may want to either exclude "No Matching Major" or log scale your y-axis to make the data more 'readable'.

Comment: I bet this works better with the bars going sideways and the categories listed flat on the left, maybe with line breaks, shorter names, and/or grouping minor categories into "other."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

kate. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Generally, your values are too detailed. I am afraid it will not look good in any angle.

I would suggest you consider other aspects like Jon Spring says, e.g., using abbreviations if you do want to show all the groups. Below is a simple way to take all the first letters of your major groups.

```
Get_abbr<- function(temp) {
  temp%<>%str_split(temp, "\\,|(and)|\\/")
  for(i in 1:length(temp)){
    temp[[i]]%<>%str_replace_all(' ', '')%>%
      str_sub(1, 1)%>%
      str_flatten()
    }
  return(temp)
}
#example data with very long string like yours
total_barbies_per_major<-data.frame(majors=c('Engineering, Computer and Materials', 'Agriculteral/Animal and Culinary Service'), stringsAsFactors = F)
> total_barbies_per_major
                                    majors
1      Engineering, Computer and Materials
2 Agriculteral/Animal and Culinary Service

#apply the function and get abbreviated
> total_barbies_per_major$majors%<>%
    sapply(FUN= Get_abbr)
#there you go
> total_barbies_per_major
  majors
1    ECM
2    AAC
```

Also, consider use `col=Majors` in your `aes()` with removing x axis to distinguish groups by color showing on a legend, and add `+coord_flip()` to rotate the plot 90°, so you don't have a flying plot.